# Ensure move in std vector with trivial type

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

Say I have a vector of ints

`std::vector<int16_t> samples;`

Is there a nice way to disable copying into this vector so that only moving is allowed? I know about `std::move`, but I'd like something like a compile error (like unique_ptr) if copying is attempted, rather than just relying on the programmer to "do the right thing"(tm)

Comment: Some kind of templated wrapper with copy constructor disabled?

Comment: What's the problem you are trying to solve? Why would move or copy make a difference with trivial types?

Comment: It's quite a lot of data (several MB), and I'd rather not copy that if at all possible (unless i'm getting the wrong idea about how expensive copying is)

Comment: I would expect the same speed for moving `int16_t` and copying them.  Maybe you use a reference/pointer of the whole vector instead of cipying it.

Comment: Unless I am missing something, cost of copy and move of trivial types should be almost identical.

Comment: I think he's talking about moving the whole vector not types within it :)

Comment: @RSahu: Copying 900MB of integers will take significantly longer than simply swapping pointers to that data.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I understand that part. Based on *disable copying into this vector so that only moving is allowed*, I thought the OP was talking about individual elements of the `vector`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an uncopyable wrapper:

```
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
class   uncopyable
{
public:
  uncopyable(const uncopyable&) = delete;

  uncopyable(uncopyable&&) = default;

  uncopyable(T&& data)
    :
    data_(std::move(data))
  {
  }

public:
  uncopyable&   operator=(const uncopyable&) = delete;

  uncopyable&   operator=(uncopyable&&) = default;

  uncopyable&   operator=(T&& data)
  {
    data_ = std::move(data);
    return *this;
  }

private:
  T       data_;
};

int     main()
{
  std::vector<int>      big(10000);

  uncopyable<std::vector<int>>  uncopyable_big(std::move(big));

  std::vector<int>      other_big(10000);

  uncopyable_big = std::move(other_big);
}
```

And use this type instead of your `vector`if you want to guarantee no copies are made.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a class member, then just make it private and only allow access in the ways you want:

```
std::vector<int16_t> const & get_samples() {return samples;}
void set_samples(std::vector<int16_t> && s) {samples = std::move(s);}
```

Otherwise, there's not much you can do to enforce particular access patterns.